# Copying documentation-like answer from Q&A to Documentation

Tags: discussion, documentation

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/topic-requests/1373) is a Python list slicing topic request.

There is a pretty good detailed answer about list slicing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation).

**My Question:**

**Part I:**
Is it OK to copy and paste OP's (Greg Hewgill's) answer to a question posted in Q&A about list slicing into a documentation section about list slicing? I suspect not! Is there a protocol for this kind of thing so that we don't have to retype all the great, already written, documentation-like answers out there for the new documentation feature? What are the alternatives to incorporating his answer into the Documentation section?

**Part II:**
In a broader sense, how do we aggregate great already-written content into the new Documentation feature, and give credit where credit is due?

Comment: You can copy and paste it in, as long as you [give proper attribution](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).